# What are the Dead Ghosts for?

Tags: destiny

I have noticed a few around the place, but so far after collecting a few, they don't appear to do anything. I have to go online to even see how many I have found, and even that seems unsatisfyingly simple.

> Dead Ghosts Found: 8

I'm pretty sure I have only found 3. Do story ghosts count as well? If so; I've found 4.

Are they just collectibles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are collectables that increase your grimoire score and give you new lore cards to look at within the Destiny mobile app or on Bungie's website.

Comment: They also have a related Achievement/Trophy if you collect at least 50. There are 62 deactivated ghosts sprinkled throughout the game.

Comment: Which you can't do anymore if you play on Xbox 360 or Playstation 3